# Excel: Combine and sort table

Tags: excel, combinations

I would like to combine the following data based on a non-unique key. I am not sure if that is possible easily. I attached a picture with the situation. I have a group of fast and slow customers who buy a product at time t. Each F# and S# indicates a purchase point. I would like to combine these, sorted by time. If time is equal (as in S2 and F4, I am indifferent which one comes first, I just need a row for each. The table beyond the arrow shows what I need. Is there a non-macro way to do it? The thing is that the time points are up to uncertainty and change, which is why I need an automatic way to sort it like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a no-macro way to do this, but it's based on a few steps and limited in a way

You put the fast range in one sheet, say "F", starting at `A1`
The slow range in another sheet, say "S", starting at `A1`

In a 3rd sheet, say "src" you combine the 2 tables:
that is, `src!B1` will hold the formula:  `=F!A1`
and this will be dragged up to `src!C1000`
staring at `src!C1001` the formula: `=S!A1`
dragged up to `src!C2000`

On src!A2, we start with a new formula, down the range to A2000, `=SMALL($C$2:$C$2000, ROW()-1)`
This formula will help us sort through both tables, now unioned in sheet src

In a 4th sheet "results" we'll add a running range from 1 to 2000, say on column A, so A1 will be 1, A2 =2 etc.

All we have left now is vlookups, in the results sheet, starting at B1, dragging to B2000:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1, src!$A$2:$C$2000, 2,0)
```

And in C1 dragging to C2000:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1, src!$A$2:$C$2000, 3,0)
```

Hope that helps